# make listview RelativeLayout align on every item

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a problem using lsitview relativelayout on android, results do not match what I want,

result look like this;

[image]

mycode;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to make it align each item, like a table, to make it more presentable and easier to read like this

[image]

NOTE: it's a listview, I use this code to put it with `android xml layout file`, code above is for `list1` `xml layout file` and below is in `activity`

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(LihatBangsal.this, mylistRuper,
                            R.layout.list1, new String[] { "ruper", "kelas", "nama", "noregis", "rm","umur", "jk" }, 
                            new int[] { R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2,R.id.textView3, R.id.textView4, R.id.textView5, R.id.textView6, R.id.textView7});
                    listBangsal.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Do you want to align each item?

Comment: yes, that's what I mean, sorry for my english

Comment: @student080705639: where are you using listview in the above code? you have arranged a set of textviews which you want them to appear as a text view?

Comment: You need to fix the width of all the textview. Also you need to make the listview layout_width = match_parent in the xml.

Comment: Could you please show an image of what really you want?Is it a listview?

Comment: The layout.xml whose code you have pasted here in that you need to fix a width for all your textview. I believe you are passing this layout into a Listview. So please make that listview' width = match_parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to emulate a ListView using TextViews? If that's correct, you need to create or set a 'style' to each TextView, adding them a:

```
android:layout_marginX="<NUMBER>"
```

where X it's Left,Right,Top,Bottom, or just margin to set the four margins.
Also try to use RelativeLayout's properties like `android:layout_alignLeft="<CHILD>"`

Try with this page to look for RelativeLayout properties
[Android RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html)

Comment: thanks, I add manually in layout_marginLeft and everything is align

Answer (score 0):

May me this will help if you set " android:id="@+id/textView2"  "  visible is gone means you will get like that alignment. Set visiblility as invisible then you will get correct alignment...

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width of textview(whose background is black or its a black bar) to max possible value and if there is no text to display then you can make textview visibility to invisible.